# Can't assign json data from controller to data in HighStock

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

I'm trying to load json data from controller Jsonresult in MVC 4 but it doesn't seems to work in HighStock. The data was serialized and the alert it popping up and displaying the data. I don't know why the chart is not rendering. But it is working when i create a variable like var data = [1,2] in the javascript function.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
           
            $.getJSON('GetData', function (data) {
                alert(data);
                var data1 = [1, 2];
                alert(data1);
                // Create the chart
                $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 1
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
                    },

                    series: [{
                        name: 'AAPL',
                        data: data,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueDecimals: 2
                        }
                    }]
                });
            });

        });
```

`[HttpGet]
      public JsonResult GetData()
      {
         string sample = "[1,2]";
         var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
         var output = jss.Serialize( sample );
         return Json( output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
      }`

Comment: It's hard to tell what's exactly up without seeing an example of the data being returned from your service, but a common cause of this behavior is where your data being returned is a String instead of a Number.

Comment: I'm getting "[1,2]" as data. What's the proper way to return a json data. Any sample code snippet?

Comment: Ok, it might be that you need to parse your response, using `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: it parsing a correct json data when using JSON.parse(data), [1,2]. But when i assign to series: data:data it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Is there any way that you can try and replicate this in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)/[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s4fex3v8/ . But call to get JsonResult GetData() not parsing the json as [1,2]

Comment: Could you tell us format of your data? Try it: `console.log(typeof data)`. If your data is string then try this: `data: JSON.parse(data),`.

Comment: I'm converting DateTime from SQL server . https://jsfiddle.net/tmdyqm5q/